# Where does the Bazaar OS X installer put the executable?

Tags: eclipse, macos, bazaar

I recently installed Bazaar on my Mac laptop and I'm trying to get bzreclipse working.  In order to do that, I need to tell it where the bzr executable is.  I can't figure out where the installer put it.  Anyone know what the default location is for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open up a terminal and do a `which bzr`. That should tell you the path to the executable.